# PulltoRefresh + await FadeTo+TranslateTo animation combination Crash on Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, async-await, xamarin.forms

I'm making app with using Xamarin.forms PCL.

I'm having really hard time to solve this issue.
I've spent several days but couldn't solve.

I'm using this nuget

- PullToRefresh 
  https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-PullToRefreshLayout
- xabre ble plugin
  https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le

When I use this at the same time AND Add some animation on the page.
It gives this runtime exception when I try to refresh. (It happens very rare like 1 time on 10 times)

- The Crash happens ONLY iOS.
- It's very rare. You can try to refresh more than 10 times. You will see.
- It happens only actual iOS Device.

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSGenericException Reason: *** Collection <__NSSetM: 0x14feb8b0> was
>   mutated while being enumerated.

I know well what this is and when this happen. 
It happens when I try to access deleted item on list or different thread.

So I made very simple source code to look this issue simply.
I don't have any list or array on my code.
Well, it happens again.

https://github.com/myallb/test_pulltorefresh

This is my sample source code for reproducing this issue. If you can help me, please look this code.

- The Crash happens ONLY iOS.
- It's very rare. You can try to refresh more than 10 times. You will see.
- It happens only actual iOS Device.

Thanks so much.

- Full source code

  using Xamarin.Forms;
      using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Contracts;
      using Plugin.BLE;
      using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.EventArgs;
      using System;
      using System.Diagnostics;
      using Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh;
      using System.Threading.Tasks;

  ```
  namespace test
  {
      public partial class testPage : ContentPage
      {
          public static IAdapter Adapter { set; get; }

          public PullToRefreshLayout RefreshView = null;
          AbsoluteLayout layout;

          public testPage()
          {
              InitializeComponent();

              Adapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;

              if (Adapter != null)
              {
                  Adapter.DeviceAdvertised += OnEvent_DeviceAdvertised;
                  Adapter.DeviceConnected += OnEvent_DeviceConnected;
                  Adapter.DeviceConnectionLost += OnEvent_DeviceConnectionLost;
                  Adapter.DeviceDisconnected += OnEvent_DeviceDisconnected;
                  Adapter.DeviceDiscovered += OnEvent_DeviceDiscovered;

                  Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), Timer_ScanDevice);
              }
              else {

              }

              layout = new AbsoluteLayout()
              {
                  BackgroundColor = Color.Purple,
              };

              ScrollView scrollview = new ScrollView()
              {
                  VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                  HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                  Content = layout
              };

              RefreshView = new PullToRefreshLayout
              {
                  VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                  HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                  Content = scrollview,
                  RefreshColor = Color.Red,
                  RefreshCommand = new Command(RefreshStart)
              };
              RefreshView.IsPullToRefreshEnabled = true;

              Content = RefreshView;

              Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), ani);
          }


          bool ani()
          {
              Label z = new Label()
              {
                  Text = "Z",
                  TextColor = Color.White,
                  FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                  FontSize = new Random().Next(22, 35)
              };

              AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(z, new Rectangle(0.67 + new Random().Next(0, 10) / 100.0, 0.13 + new Random().Next(0, 10) / 100.0, 40, 40));
              AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(z, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
              layout.Children.Add(z);

              Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
              {
                  Task t1 = z.FadeTo(0, 3500);
                  Task t2 = z.TranslateTo(0, -70, 3500, Easing.SinInOut);

                  await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
                  layout.Children.Remove(z);
              });

              return true;
          }

          void RefreshStart()
          {
              Debug.WriteLine("RefreshStart");

              if (RefreshView != null)
                  RefreshView.IsRefreshing = true;

              Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
              {
                  await Task.Delay(20);

                  Debug.WriteLine("RefreshEnd");
                  RefreshView.IsRefreshing = false;
              });
          }

          bool Timer_ScanDevice()
          {
              Adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync();

              return true;
          }


          void OnEvent_DeviceAdvertised(object sender, DeviceEventArgs a)
          {
              Debug.WriteLine("OnEvent_DeviceAdvertised");
          }

          void OnEvent_DeviceDiscovered(object sender, DeviceEventArgs a)
          {
              Debug.WriteLine("OnEvent_DeviceDiscovered");
          }

          void OnEvent_DeviceConnected(object sender, DeviceEventArgs a)
          {
              Debug.WriteLine("OnEvent_DeviceConnected");
          }

          void OnDeviceProcessError(IDevice device, string message)
          {
              Debug.WriteLine("OnDeviceProcessError");
          }

          void OnEvent_DeviceConnectionLost(object sender, DeviceErrorEventArgs a)
          {
              Debug.WriteLine("OnEvent_DeviceConnectionLost");
          }

          void OnEvent_DeviceDisconnected(object sender, DeviceEventArgs a)
          {
              Debug.WriteLine("OnEvent_DeviceDisconnected");
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I tried to remove all ble modules, and still got crash.

Comment: Try moving layout.Children.Add(z); into your async block (Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread())

Comment: It's same result. @sellotape. Device.Starttimer guarantee it's on Main thread.